# Custom eigenvalue in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, eigenvalue

Is there any way to solve a custom eigenvalue problem like (A*l^2+B*l+C)x=0 in MATLAB using its functions? (A, B and C are matrices and l is my eigenvalue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you are trying to solve for `I` or not, but if you are, I suggest you look at

[polyeig](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/polyeig.html)